# AngularJS: directive adds object to $scope but undefined in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to AngularJS.
I wanna use [angular-bootstrap-tour](https://github.com/benmarch/angular-bootstrap-tour) to create a walk-through. It says:

> The tour directive creates a wrapper that contains all tour steps and adds the tour object to the scope.

So I have this code in my view:

```
<div tour placement="top">
   <div tour-step order="0" title="Main Menu" content="This is the main menu." placement="bottom">
</div>
```

And now in my controller, I wanna use this code to start the tour as the page loads:

```
$scope.tour.restart(tour);
```

But it says: `$scope.tour is undefined!`
and when I add the code below to my view, the buttons start the tour! How tour is defined in view but not in controller's `$scope`?

```
<button class="btn" ng-click="tour.restart(true)">Start Tour</button>
```

Comment: Where are you executing `$scope.tour.restart(tour);` ? Depending on the version of AngularJS you're using, you probably want to execute this in the ngOnInit hook.

But you probably need to add some more code to provide some more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Code in your js file like

```
    function execute(moduleType) {
        if(moduleType) {
           var tour = new Tour({orphan: false});
           tour.addSteps(setRoute(moduleType));
           tour.init();
           tour.restart();
           tour.start(true);
        }
    }
```

Add Code in your HTML file like

```
<button class="btn" ng-click="execute(true)">Start Tour</button>
```

Comment: Afaik, the OP indicated there's no issue with using: `<button class="btn" ng-click="tour.restart(true)">Start Tour</button> `.

Comment: Thanks that helped me to know how to use Tour class and may solve my problem; but my question is still not answered.